# Hibernate Eager select hangs in "Idle in transaction"

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

In my project I'm using hibernate 3, Spring and C3p0 and after consulting postgres' pg_stat_activity I strongly suspect this query to be from hibernate query to populate an EAGER list in one of my entities

```
select listrulesf0_.rule_block_register_id as rule4_15_1_, listrulesf0_.id as id1_16_1_, listrulesf0_.id as id1_16_0_, listrulesf0_.display_order as display2_16_0_, listrulesf0_.id_field as id3_16_0_, listrulesf0_.rule_block_register_id as rule4_16_0_ from (...)
```

this query hangs idle in transaction effectively blocking every other operation in my program.

I have no idea how this happens and how I can fix it.

Comment: not likely, i know, but maybe this helps? http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=64905

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't the EAGER select, but the flush that came after it

[IDLE in transaction when using entity manager flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385544/idle-in-transaction-when-using-entity-manager-flush)